# Offset object duplicated along path

Tags: animation, modifiers, bezier-curves, constraints

I have a curve and a sphere, and I would like to make 5 copies of that sphere move along the curve.

It's possible to duplicate them along the curve by making the sphere a child of the curve and switching on dupliframes, however don't know how to move the duplicated spheres along the path - perhaps there's an `offset` option I'm missing?

Using the a `Follow Path` constraint I can offset the sphere along the path, but I can't duplicate it.

I've also tried the `Array` and `Curve` modifiers together - again this doesn't let me move the duplicated spheres along the path.

Any suggestions?

[image: Five spheres moving along a path]

Comment: Is there a problem using 5 instances of the same sphere with "Follow path"? Or maybe making a mesh with 5 vertices and using the sphere as dupliobject?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to obtain what you describe: it wasn't extremely simple, but I think the result should be something near, at least:

[image]

How it is done?

- added the path
- added a 5 vertex segment
- added a curve modifier to the segment (highlighted in the above image), targeting the curve, along X
- now moving the segment along X (animating with loc keyframes) it follows the curve
- then added 5 spheres, each snapped to each of the segment vertices, then each vertex parented to the segment
- alternatively, and more efficiently, you can parent one sphere to the segment, then select the segment and enable duplication on "verts".

the following images show the alternative method, and also a movement along a more complicated curve:

[image]

[image]

there are probably other ways, but this should be near.