# Looping an array and curve modifier animation of object moving along a path?

Tags: animation

Help make this animation in Blender.
Modifier array and Curve, but what's next?
I need the arrows to cycle along the wire. If the arrow has reached the end, it should appear at the beginning

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please add more details ?

Comment: Just animate position of the arrow along X or Y axis

Comment: I need the arrows to cycle along the wire. If the arrow has reached the end, it should appear at the beginning
https://i.imgur.com/FiD9NVq.png

Comment: related/similar: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65943/offset-object-duplicated-along-path

Comment: this effect I did, I do not know how to make the next step.

Comment: [Also Related / Similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89098/loop-multiple-objects-along-the-same-path)

Comment: @cegaton  meant to vote to leave open, edited to specify my reason and forgot that voted edit.  IMO if i was to  answer here, using edited version of my answer in dupe would a better option than addendum-ing my  answer there for this specific case.  What do you think?

Comment: @batFINGER given the enthusiastic answer from the OP sounded like a dupe... vote retracted.

Answer (score -1):

you can cut the animation so that when it reaches the endpoint it will restart. To do that you only have to reduce the time line that is in the bottom of your screen where you place the keys frames